# QImage read pixel data with precision

Tags: c++, qt, pixel, qimage

Sorry for the basic question, I am just starting to use [QImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html) for reading pixel data from an image file.

To understand the member functions, I tried to load an image file and tried to output the functions return values:

```
QString fileName = "pic1.bmp";
QImage myImage;
myImage.load( fileName );

std::cout << "width = "         << myImage.width() << std::endl;
std::cout << "height = "        << myImage.height() << std::endl;
std::cout << "dotspermeterX = " << myImage.dotsPerMeterX() << std::endl;
std::cout << "dotspermeterY = " << myImage.dotsPerMeterY() << std::endl;
QRectF myRect = myImage.rect();
std::cout << "rect = " << myRect.bottomLeft().x() << "," << myRect.bottomLeft().y()
      << "  " << myRect.topRight().x() << "," << myRect.topRight().y() << std::endl;
```

The output I got was:

```
width = 858
height = 608
dotspermeterX = 4724
dotspermeterY = 4724
rect = 0,608  858,0
```

My questions are:
1. What is the difference between `dots` and `pixels`?
2. Does QImage work only with `int` pixels? Can't I read sub-pixel data for better precision?

To clarify my question, Following is a zoomed bitmap image of a diagonal line and I want to read all the small pixels/dots in this line. Is this possible?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the "dots per meter", you probably heard of "dots per inch" (or DPI). It's the same. If, for example, you have a 20 inch monitor with the horizontal resolution of X pixels, you will have Y "dots per inch" (or pixels per inch). If you then switch to a 40 inch monitor but with the same horizontal resolution X, then you have *half* the number of DPI, as the screen is now double as wide. So DPI (or PPI) can be seens as a measurement of the size of the pixels.

And no, I seriously doubt that `QImage` have any support for sub-pixel data.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. So dots and pixels are the same thing, right? Also in the image I have shown, the small black squares I assume are pixels, so reading them shall be possible with QImage right?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Yes, dots and pixels are the same. And yes, you can read the single pixels of a `QImage` and so should be able to find the black pixels in an otherwise white bitmap quite easily.